# Is this modern, standard German?

Tags: standard-german

I bought an ebook titled "Five Great German Short Stories" for the purpose of improving my German reading comprehension and vocabulary. It's a collection of historical short stories.  I'd like to know if this is "normal" modern German, or if it is a style from 100 to 200 years ago.

Sample 1, author Heinrich von Kleist:

> Es war am Fronleichnamsfeste, und die feierliche Prozession der Nonnen, welchen die Novizen folgten, nahm eben ihren Anfang, als die unglückliche Josephe bei dem Anklange der Glocken in Mutterwehen auf den Stufen der Kathedrale niedersank. Dieser Vorfall machte außerordentliches Aufsehn; man brachte die junge Sünderin ohne Rücksicht auf ihren Zustand sogleich in ein Gefängnis, und kaum war sie aus den Wochen erstanden, als ihr schon auf Befehl des Erzbischofs der geschärfteste Prozeß gemacht ward.

Sample 2, author Thomas Mann:

> Nach wie vor leitet Doktor Leander die Anstalt. Mit seinem zwei-spitzigen schwarzen Bart, der hart und kraus ist wie das Roßhaar, mit dem man die Möbel stopft, seinen dicken, funkelnden Brillengläsern und diesem Aspekt eines Mannes, den die Wissenschaft gekältet, gehärtet und mit stillem, nachsichtigem Pessimismus erfüllt hat, hält er auf kurz angebundene und verschlossene Art die Leidenden in seinem Bann, – alle diese Individuen, die, zu schwach, sich selbst Gesetze zu geben und sie zu halten, ihm ihr Vermögen ausliefern, um sich von seiner Strenge stützen lassen zu dürfen.

Source: Appelbaum, Stanley. Five Great German Short Stories: A Dual-Language Book (Dover Dual Language German). Dover Publications. Kindle Edition.

Comment: You know when the texts were written, right? So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Both texts are good for that purpose. They are both a bit old-fashioned but not as old-fashioned as for example Shakespeare is for English readers.

Comment: Heinreich von Kleiste appears non-standard todaye but readable. Thomas Mann may be a reading assignment in high school.

Comment: Janka they may be for a native speaker but esp. Mann is hard to read due to syntactic overcomplication. Also what @vectory says.

Comment: You should go with graded readers or simple **modern** books like "Tschick". We also happen to have a list of such books somewhere on this website.

Answer (score 5):

It's always a good idea to improve ones foreign language skills by reading books written in this language. Unfortunately at least one of these two texts won't help you.

Heinrich von Kleist was born in 1777 and died in 1811, so we can say, that this short story is at least 200 years old. Looking at the story every native speaker will tell you, that its language is old fashioned and "no one speaks like this today". It will help you improve your vocabulary (I believe a lot of Germans don't know >[aus den Wochen erstanden](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~in%20den%20Wochen%20sein%3B%20in%20die%20Wochen%20kommen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)< either ^^), but you won't be able to use these words or structures in everyday language. Unless you want to sound like a time traveller ;) . So ... learning/improving German by reading Kleist is like learning/improving English by reading Shakespeare.

Thomas Mann on the other hand was born in 1875 and died in 1955, so his language is more modern. A lot of his books are regualry read in school, especially the Buddenbrooks and they could be published even today. But ... Thomas Mann is known for his "[Bandwurmsätze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwurmsatz)" ([endless sentences](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotaxe)). Take a look at [this pdf](http://www.alternativ-grammatik.de/pdfs/mann3.pdf) showing his longest sentence.

These very long sentences make Mann hard to read, so it might be challenging for you, but maybe that's what you are looking for. In everyday language most sentences will be much shorter ^^.

Comment: Kleist is much nearer to contemporary German than Shakespeare to contemporary English. I agree with the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Is this modern German? No. Is it standard German? I do not see anything in either extract that is not "standard" in terms of morphology and syntax. If it is "for the purpose of improving my German reading comprehension and vocabulary" you can hardly do better than reading authors like Kleist or Mann.

I actually think that the whole point of learning foreign languages is so that you can read the best classical and modern authors of another culture in their own words. If you really just want to buy a beer in Germany you can do that in English.